# Is there any way to SET client_encoding TO 'UTF8' permanent?

Tags: postgresql, psql

I connect to my db from console using command:

```sql
psql -U postgres task_db
```

and did this select query :

```sql
select * from common.task;
```

I received this Error:

```
ERROR:  character with byte sequence 0xe5 0xb0 0x8f in encoding "UTF8" has no equivalent in encoding "WIN1252"
```

And followed this command from this answer to fix this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38487921/7505731

```sql
SET client_encoding TO 'UTF8';
```

It worked.

**Problem** : Now I have to run above command every time I connect to db from command line. Is there any way I can set this encoding permanent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to set this command in your [`.psqlrc` file](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html#id-1.9.4.18.10):

> Unless it is passed an -X option, psql attempts to read and execute commands from the system-wide startup file (psqlrc) and then
>   the user's personal startup file (~/.psqlrc), after connecting to the
>   database but before accepting normal commands. These files can be used
>   to set up the client and/or the server to taste, typically with \set
>   and SET commands.
>
> The system-wide startup file is named psqlrc and is sought in the installation's “system configuration” directory, which is most
>   reliably identified by running pg_config --sysconfdir. By default this
>   directory will be ../etc/ relative to the directory containing the
>   PostgreSQL executables. The name of this directory can be set
>   explicitly via the PGSYSCONFDIR environment variable.
>
> The user's personal startup file is named .psqlrc and is sought in the invoking user's home directory. On Windows, which lacks such a
>   concept, the personal startup file is named
>   %APPDATA%\postgresql\psqlrc.conf. The location of the user's startup
>   file can be set explicitly via the PSQLRC environment variable.
>
> Both the system-wide startup file and the user's personal startup file can be made psql-version-specific by appending a dash and the
>   PostgreSQL major or minor release number to the file name, for example
>   ~/.psqlrc-9.2 or ~/.psqlrc-9.2.5. The most specific version-matching
>   file will be read in preference to a non-version-specific file.