# Encoding issue in Postgres ERROR "UTF8" is it best to set encoding to UTF8 or to make the data WIN1252 compatible?

Tags: sql, postgresql, encoding, utf-8, psql

I created a table importing a CSV file from an excel spreadsheet. When I try to run the select statement below I get the error.

```
test=# SELECT * FROM dt_master;
ERROR:  character with byte sequence 0xc2 0x9d in encoding "UTF8" has no equivalent in encoding "WIN1252"
```

I have read the solution posted [in this stack overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38481829/postgresql-character-with-byte-sequence-0xc2-0x81-in-encoding-utf8-has-no-equ) and was able to overcome the issue by setting the encoding to UTF8, so up to that point I am still able to keep working with the data. My question, however, is whether setting the encoding to UTF8 actually is solving the problem or it is just a workaround that and will create other problems down the road and I would be better off removing the conflicting characters and making the data WIN1252 compliant.
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You have a weird character in your database (Unicode code point 9D, a control character) that probably got there by mistake.

You have to set the client encoding to the encoding that your application expects; no other value will produce correct results, even if you get rid of the error. The error has a reason.

You have two choices:

- Fix the data in the database. The character is very likely not what was intended.
- Change the application to use LATIN1 or (better) UTF-8 internally and set the client encoding appropriately.

Using UTF-8 everywhere would have the advantage that you are safe from this kind of problem.

Comment: Triggered by UTF-8 everywhere (on windows 10), I tried several approaches. The latest is a setting in Time&Language->Language->adminstrative language settings->change system locale -> Beta:use Unicode UTF-8 for worldwide language support.
psql then says: could not determine encoding for locale "English_United States.utf8": codeset is "CPutf8". My db's are already in UTF8, including collation and Ctype.
Do you think this languagesetting is a way to go to achieve UTF-8 everywhere (wr to postgresql, particularly), or is there a way to help psql, except \encoding utf8 each time?

Comment: Adding to last comment: after starting psql, typing \encoding ENTER yields UTF8.
So the client side seems ok.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe, yes, when I opened my data en VSCode and chose WIN1252 to see it, there were multiple characters being showed wrong, I noticed that many of them were fractions that were automatically converted by excel to the smaller font fraction type. The problem is that there seem to be many (maybe hundreds) of problems. So from your response, I get that using UTF-8 should not be an issue and is probably better than attempting to correct each problematic character to make it compatible with WIN1252 correct?

Comment: No. You have to figure out what encoding your VSCode uses. Since this is old software on Windows, perhaps it uses WINDOWS-1252. In that case you would be lost, because this character just cannot be represented in that encoding (as the error message tells you). You'd have to change the character in the database.

Comment: Got it, I will try to figure out how to find the wrong characters without having to read one by one.