# How to convert old postgresql db from ascii to utf8

Tags: postgresql, utf-8, ascii

I have this old database from postgresql version 8.4 that my boss told me to try to convert from SQL_ASCII encoding to UTF8 encoding.
I tried to `pg_dump --encoding=UTF8` and I got the message "invalid byte sequence for encoding “UTF8” : 0xe76122"
And searching more i tried `pg_dump --encoding=ISO88591`, and it worked, and I could also import it with no problems to the new empty UTF8 database that i created, but from time to time, i'm getting this message: "ERROR: character 0xc296 with encoding "UTF8" has no equivalent in "WIN1252";". Any solutions?

Comment: First an encoding of  `SQL_ASCII` essentially meant no encoding was enforced, so it is possible to have content in different encodings in a database. Second, what are you doing when you get the error message? Third, what happens if you import with `--encoding=WIN1252`?

Comment: So, for the 1° I'm not sure, but probably it is, if so what could I do?
for the 2° the database is used for an ERP software, so when i launch the software and go to some menus, and error pop-up appears with this sql error inside. For the 3°, i think you're suggesting I export as WIN1252, right? If so, i just tried, and when i try to import it in my UTF-8 database it gives me te error that "character 0x81 with encoding "WIN1252" has no equivalent in "UTF8""

Comment: See this SO post [Encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38481829/postgresql-character-with-byte-sequence-0xc2-0x81-in-encoding-utf8-has-no-equ). One of the answers mentions ODBC driver. Are you using ODBC and if so what driver?

Comment: Hello. I'm using ODBC and it is ANSI. Should I try with ISO again and OBDC UNICODE?

Comment: I'm not sure what `ISO` is referring to? Given that the database is now using the `UTF8` encoding I would say the `ODBC UNICODE` driver would be the one to use.

Comment: Hey I just wanted to say I figured it out thanks to your ODBC tip. I converted my SQL_ASCII DB  to ISO88591 which is LATIN1, and them imported in an new UTF8 DB, changed my ODBC driver to UNICODE and it works fine!

Answer (score 3):

You made a mistake in converting the database.

It must have been encoded in WINDOWS-1252, not ISO 8859-1, and there must have been an “em dash” (Unicode U+2013, code point 96 in WINDOWS-1252).

When you dumped the database with encoding `LATIN1` = `ISO88591` and loaded it, the byte 0x96 was interpreted as Unicode U+0096, which is 0xC296 in UTF-8. This character does not exist in WINDOWS-1252, so the conversion fails.

You have to dump and restore the database again, but this time use

```sh
pg_dump --encoding=WIN1252
```

Since you also have code point 0x81 in your database, it could aso be `WIN1251` (Cyrillic) or `WIN1256` (Arabic). Or you have some wild mix – then you must fix the data before migration.

Comment: See comment from @AndréLucas above where the above was attempted with a different error. My suspicion is there are multiple encodings in the original data.

Comment: I have commented on that in my answer.

Comment: I use a portuguese language on my software, there is a lot of accents and ççç, is that maybe why?

Comment: No, it has to do with the encoding that the database clients used.