# How to prevent special characters from being corrupted when using UTF8 encoding in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, psql, postgresql-10

I'm using **PostgreSQL** DB with **UTF8** encoding and I'm trying to fetch some data using `psql.exe`.

My table `diacritics` contains the following data:

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Kočička |
| 2 | Mňau |

As you can see, there are a few (Czech) characters with diacritics. They are displayed correctly when viewed in pgAdmin, however, when I try to fetch the same data using `psql.exe`, the special characters get corrupted:

```
 id |   name
----+-----------
  1 | Ko─ìi─ìka
  2 | M┼êau
(2 rows)
```

I manually set *client encoding* to **UTF8** as mentioned [in this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38487921/6283557) as I was getting the same error message as the OP there.

My resulting command looks like this (I'm running it in *PowerShell*):

```
./psql.exe -h localhost -p 5433 -U postgres -d experimental -c "SET client_encoding TO 'UTF8'; SELECT * FROM diacritics"
```

I would expect to get the data with the correct diacritics as the encoding on both sides matches. I tried outputting the fetched data into a file to rule out the possibility that it's a *PowerShell* related issue but had no success.

Also, I can fetch the data correctly in *C#* using *Npgsql* package so the problem only seems to be related to using `psql.exe`.

I'm using PostgreSQL 10.20 (10.0.20.22038). I have also tried it on version 14.2 (14.0.2.22041) and the results are the same.

Comment: It is almost certainly your terminal not having the correct character encoding set.